# Show that the three vector fields $X, Y$ and $Z$ on $\Bbb R^3$ are tangent to the $2$-sphere $\Bbb S^2$.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

> Show that the three vector fields $X = y\frac{\partial}{\partial z}-z\frac{\partial}{\partial y}, Y = z\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $Z=x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ on $\Bbb R^3$ are tangent to the $2$-sphere $\Bbb S^2$.

I have a definition that a vector field is tangent to submanifold $S \subseteq M$ if for all $p \in S$ the tangent vector $X_p$ is in $T_pS \subseteq T_pM$.

I don't really know how to approach the problem. Why is $X_p$ neccessarily a tangent vector? Using coordinate charts it seems that $X_p$ is of form $$X_p = \sum_{i=1}^n X^i(p) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \bigg|_p$$ but what is this $X^i(p)$ here?

John Lee's book also suggests that $X$ is tangent to a submanifold $S$ if and only if $(Xf) \mid_S = 0$ for every $f \in C^\infty(M)$ such that $f\mid_S \equiv 0$.

Can I use either one of these definitions here?

Comment: In your case, say $p \in \mathbb S^2$, what is $T_p\mathbb S^2$ as a subspace of $T_p \mathbb R^3$?

Comment: It's the tangent plane at $p$ right? So in a sense $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: Yes it's a two dimensional subspace of $T_p\mathbb R^3$, but exactly which one? How does it related to $p$?

Comment: It's spanned by the directional derivatives/derivations at $p$?

Comment: Yes, can you write down explicitly which map you take the directional derivative with?

Comment: The sphere is defined by $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1$ so $p = (x,y,z)$ such that $\|p\| = 1$. I suppose I have to relate the vector fields somehow with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a hint: The sphere is the collection of points $(x,y,z)$ such that $f(x,y,z)=0$ where $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1$.  Following Lee's suggestion, a necessary condition to be tangent is for $Xf|_S=0$.  This van be verified for these 3 vector fields.  Can you show that this is sufficient?

Comment: I think my issue is with not really understanding the concept here. The partial derivatives in $X = y\frac{\partial}{\partial z}-z\frac{\partial}{\partial y}, Y = z\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $Z=x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ are essentially basis vectors for the tangent space right? So do you mean that I need to check each of $Xf|_S=0, Yf|_S=0$ and $Zf|_S=0$ to verify this?

Comment: Yes, you need to check each of those.  This is 3 different problems that you need to do the same thing for.  And yes, the partial derivatives are vector fields on $\mathbb R^3$, and at each point those 3 will form a basis for the tangent space.  A vector yields (by the directional derivative evaluated at a point) a map satisfying the product rule, and one can show that every map satisfying the product rule comes from a vector, and so vector fields are the same as derivations from smooth functions to smooth functions.  In coordinates, they are built up out of the partials.

Answer (score 1):

By Proposition $5.38$ in John Lee's book "Smooth manifolds" (2. Edition), $T_p\mathbb S^2=\ker df_{|p}$, where $f:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$, $(x,y,z)\mapsto x^2+y^2+z^2-1$. Now $\frac 12\mathrm{grad}f(x,y,z)=x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$. So for $p=(x,y,z)\in\mathbb S^2$, a tangent vector $v=\alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\beta\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\gamma\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\in T_p\mathbb R^3$ is tangent to $\mathbb S^2$ if and only if $\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma z=0$.